# Can the tendency toward social construction of mental illness be decoupled from responsibility?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology

Hacking, in *The social constructionism of what?*, cites Boyle's claim that patients "need" the diagnosis of schizophrenia.

He then approves of the idea that schizophrenia is an "interactive kind":

[image]

All this seems reasonable.

But has anyone combined these sorts of observations, that sufferers (I use this term literally) of schizophrenia can have degrees of "insight" (the psychiatric term for this awareness) into opinions on their condition, but nevertheless are not especially to blame for their symptomology? At least no more than people are to blame for e.g. their stupidity.

Comment: i think the point is that whatever the needs of individual patients, they are outnumbered and outgunned haha

Comment: That is kind of the profession's position.  Going all the way back to Bleuler, schizophrenics were seen as not responsible for their condition or their symptoms.  And it is obvious that many schizophrenics have either continual insight or periods of lucidity.  So, what is the question?

Comment: ok the question is easily answered then

Comment: @jobermark do you think that people who reject the label of "illness" for themselves can be wrong to? i'm maybe of the opinion that its rigidity is ultimately unsatisfactory, however much it may apply or even at times be helpful

Comment: An illness has to be troubling or impair functioning.  So there are people with symptoms of schizophrenia who are not ill.  I have worked with someone who has intense hallucinations, but experiences them as beatific visions.  She also has a certain degree of aboulia -- but submission to authority is a value of her religion.  And her sense of language is very fluid, but she is an artist, so it works for her.  She is not ill, though she clearly has schizophrenia.  She is not troubled, and her parents found a way in her youth to ensure she could 'function' in the right role.